# How to get a list from the form using Spring MVC

Tags: forms, list, spring-mvc

I have a List (List), which I have defined it at form. I want to pass this list to jsp. The framework I use is spring mvc. The difficult part to this is that I cannot populate the list. I know that I have to write a foreach statement, but I tried and nothing happened. I followed [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/) example, but the same happened again. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I have wrote the same code as the example I provided. I do not have the exact code now. I want to get the values from jsp. These values are in a List.

Comment: Start with something more basic first. Your probably not getting the List into the model. You should also know Spring uses a special `List` to do multiple objects (or at least it did when I used it last).

Comment: I think that you mean lazylist...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, for helping me to my problem. I finally found a solution.
In form I wrote `@Valid
    private SubmitAEActivityForm[] person;` Then I wrote a class that included the fields I wanted. After that in my JSP i wrote:

```
c:forEach items="${submitAEForm.aifs}" var="holdData"
                                varStatus="loop">
                                <c:set var="indexLoop" value="${loop.index}" scope="request" />
                                <c:set var="items" value="${holdData}" scope="request" />
                                <c:import url="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/prototype.jsp"></c:import>

                            </c:forEach> <c:remove var="items" />
```

prototype.jsp included the fields I wanted to clone. My jQuery code was:

```
function initDivList(addBtn, removeBtn, hiddenDivId, displayDivId) {
    var i = 0;
    $(addBtn).click(function() {
        $(hiddenDivId).clone().find('input, select').each(function() {
            $(this).attr({
                'name': function(_, name) { return name.replace("$NAME$", i); }
              }); }).end().fadeIn(1000).appendTo(displayDivId).css("display", "block");

        $(removeBtn).click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        i++;
    });
     $(removeBtn).click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        if (i > 1) {
            i--;
        }
    });
```

In this way I had each field indexed, so I could easily render each error

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?
http://viralpatel-net-tutorials.googlecode.com/files/SpringMVC_Multi_Row.zip

I imported this project into my STS and run it, then I successfully got the list of elements.

I am using following software:

- Tomcat 7.0.39
- STS 3.2.0
- Java 1.7

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your link doesn't work. Update it, ping me in the comment's and I'll remove the downvote :)

Comment: It is actually recommended to include a bit of code and an explanation as to what was the solution, if possible.